# How do I set a notification's small icon to the app's icon?

Tags: xamarin, notifications, resources, icons

I am trying to use:

`.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Mipmap.Icon)`

The build fails (with "0 errors") and the following in the output:

`error CS0117: 'Resource' does not contain a definition for 'Mipmap'`

I am flummoxed because I can Control-click on `Icon` and VS is perfectly happy to take me to the definition.

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the solution until I got bored.

Comment: which resource are you using are you using the correct namespace for your resource? 
       Correct: `YourProject.Resource.MipMap.Icon` Incorrect: `Android.Resource.MipMap.Icon`

Comment: I have checked and am referencing the project resources.

Comment: Still the same issue? If yes have you tried a restart?

Comment: If you have confrimed the path is correct, please try to close the VS, open the project with file explorer, then delete the `obj` and 'bin' file. Open the VS and run this project in the end.

Comment: Sadly, none of the above has worked.

Comment: Can you share your demo?